# What does it mean to be told to include a library or SDK in your project?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Specifically on the AWS developers documentation for setting up your own user pools with AWS Cognito it says the following:

-Download and include the Amazon Cognito AWS SDK for JavaScript from GitHub.

-Download and include the Amazon Cognito Identity SDK for JavaScript from GitHub.

-Include the JavaScript BN library for BigInteger computations from here.

-Include the Stanford Javascript Crypto Library from here.

-Include Moment.js, a JavaScript library used for date manipulation from here.

What does this mean specifically? I have downloaded these javascript files and saved them in my project and then done the following for each of them:

```
<script src="fileName"></script>
```

Is this all it means by include them?

Below is the link with the actual instructions:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/setting-up-the-javascript-sdk.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, including SDK's into your project in JavaScript only requires you to add script tags. (Unless you're using a package manager (such as npm or bower) or a build tool (such as gulp, grunt or webpack), which might require some extra steps).

All of the scripts you need have been listed after the 8. step in the instructions you linked (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/setting-up-the-javascript-sdk.html):

```
<script src="/path/to/jsbn.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/jsbn2.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/sjcl.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/aws-cognito-sdk.min.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/amazon-cognito-identity.min.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/aws-sdk-2.3.5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess what confuses me is when I click the links to download the cognito sdk for example it just link me to a ton of plain text on a page, which I save into a js file but which doesn't have the default name they listed in their examples that you cited. I guess I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: At least in Google Chrome (latest), if you click CTRL+S on the page you should be able to download the file with the right filename as default. Assuming you're talking about files linked from Github, such as https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js/master/dist/aws-cognito-sdk.min.js.